# Authentication with AzureAD via TestCafe Tests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, azure-active-directory, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm unable to authenticate / sign-in via AzureAD when running testCafe.

```js
const testrole = Role(
  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
  async t => {
    await t
      .typeText(Selector('input').withAttribute('type', 'email'), *******)
      .click(Selector('#idSIButton9'))
      .typeText(Selector('input').withAttribute('type', 'password'), ********)
      .click(Selector('#idSIButton9'));
  },
  { preserveUrl: true }
);
```

The above steps work fine, however after entering the password I get a message saying:

"Unable to sign in to Outlook account, Error: AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request."

From my initial search, it seems like something to do with 3rd party cookies on the browser. However, I'm unable to find a solution at this time.

Any idea how I get around this issue?

Comment: I now get a 'You can not get there from here' message. I am using my chrome profile and allowing the host and port, but still can't get past this message.

Answer (score 4):

The Azure AD product team has always reminded me that it is a bad idea to try to automate sign in like that.
They will probably detect that you are a bot and start blocking your requests, even if you succeed.

Instead, to acquire access tokens you need to use either the client credentials flow (for app-only tokens) or the resource owner password credentials flow (for delegated user tokens).

Client credentials flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

ROPC flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

You have to take good care to secure the credentials used for testing. 
And use a test tenant if possible.

Comment: I understand your point, but I can't seem to access the app any method i try. I get 'You can not get there from here'